# Automatically serialise child objects just from ids using JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, json.net

When an object is serialized using the default JSON.NET serialization settings, child objects and their foreign keys are set separately as below:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "postId": 22,
    "tagId": 16,
    "post": null,
    "tag": null
}
```

Because I want the objects to play nice with client side JavaScript frameworks, I want the objects to be serialized more intelligently. Entity Framework already knows that the 'post' object is the object that is represented by 'postId', but how can I tell the serializer this?

I want this json to be serialized, even if the C# instance of the class being serialized has a null Post property.

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "post": {
        "id": 22
    },
    "tag": {
        "id": 16
    }
}
```

I know that I can customize the serialization of each object using a `JsonConverter` but this involves writing a custom serializer for each type of object. I would prefer this type of serialization behaviour to be done automatically.

The above json represnts this C# class:

```
 public class ExampleBlogObject
   {      
      public int Id { get; set; }

      public int PostId { get; set; }

      public int TagId { get; set; }

      [ForeignKey("PostId")]
      public virtual Post Post { get; set; }

      [ForeignKey("TagId")]
      public virtual Tag Tag { get; set; }
   }
```

Comment: Perhaps you could set up a CustomContractResolver that looks for members that end in "Id" and serializes them properly.  Check out the documentation under http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/?topic=html/ContractResolver.htm I've never done it before so I can't give you an exact answer but maybe that will lead you in the right direction

Comment: 1) What do you want it to look like when `Post` and `Tag` are not null?  Do you want these objects to be fully serialized there?  2) Do you need deserialization?

Comment: I think Mark is on the right track with resolvers and will have to research. Essentially, even if entity frameworks lazy loading had set a Post and Tag value, the serializer should just ignore them, serializing only the foreign key 'id' properties as if they were simple objects.